# GCP MemoryStore unaccessible from Compute Engine on same region

Tags: go, google-cloud-platform, redis, google-compute-engine

I followed the two following tutorials:

- https://cloud.google.com/go/docs/tutorials/bookshelf-on-compute-engine
- https://cloud.google.com/memorystore/docs/redis/creating-managing-instances?authuser=1

The only thing I did different is that I deployed the code of Redis from the second tutorial, not from the first link.

As mentioned ["Connecting to a Redis instance"](https://cloud.google.com/memorystore/docs/redis/connecting-redis-instance) `You can connect to the Redis instance from any Compute Engine VM instance located within the same project, region and network as the Redis instance.`

> my-service: *10.162.0.17 (nic0)*
>
> redis: *10.169.12.195:6379*
>
> Same project, same region, same zone (a)

However, when I do:

```
user@my-service:~$ telnet 10.0.0.27 6379
Trying 10.0.0.27...
```

Nothing happens..

Comment: Redis is at `10.169.12.195:6379` and you are trying to connect to `10.0.0.27 6379`?

Comment: No I try to connect at the given IP. However, `telnet 10.0.0.27 6379` in the given link doesn't work for me and I don't get why

Comment: Why would you expect it to work on `10.0.0.27`? Do you have a redis service on that IP address?

Comment: I don’t really expect it to work, it’s just that, in order to test a simple ping, the documentation is using that IP and when I do, it doesn’t work. My service does work if I put the IP of the instance, I can ping as well. However, the given address from the doc doesn’t work and I am not understanding why.. sorry if it’s something stupid but I don’t get it

Comment: The address in the documentation is an example. You need to modify to match your environment/configuration.

Comment: Wooow alright I thought it was just a simple “IP mapping” or a default configuration of the machine.. thanks for your answer ! If you post an answer I will validate it then, so stupid I am !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation specifies the command `telnet 10.0.0.27 6379`. This is an example that you need to modify for your environment.

Change the command to:

```
telnet 10.169.12.195 6379
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer John !